# How to enforce contract on template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

How can I specify template parameter to be of a certain type i-e it must have implemented an interface (the template parameter must be a derived class of a specific base class)

Heres the interface (abstract base class)

```
class baseActionCounter{
public:
virtual int eat()=0;
virtual int drink()=0;
};
```

Now I want my template parameter to be of type baseActionCounter

Heres the templated class

```
//imaginary template syntax in the line below. Is there a way of achieving this behavior?
template <class counterType : baseActionCounter>

    class bigBoss{
    counterType counter;
    public:
    int consumerStats(){
    //I am able to call member function because I know that counter object has eat() and drink() 
    //because it implemented baseActionCounter abstract class
    return counter.eat() + counter.drink(); 
    }
    };
```

I can also just derive my bigBoss class from baseActionCounter but I want to know how to achieve this behavior with templates.
Also, template specialization is not suitable as there is just one BigBoss class for any implementor of baseActionCounter class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`std::is_base_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) to check the type, e.g.

```
template <class counterType, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<baseActionCounter, counterType>>* = nullptr>
class bigBoss {
```

Or

```
template <class counterType>
class bigBoss {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<baseActionCounter, counterType>, "counterType must derive from baseActionCounter");
    ...
};
```

Or use [concept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) (since C++20).

```
template <class T>
concept Derived = std::is_base_of_v<baseActionCounter, T>;

template <Derived counterType>
class bigBoss {
```

BTW: `std::is_base_of` also returns `true` if the base class `baseActionCounter` is specified; if that's not what you want you can combine the condition with `std::is_same`.

Comment: that was easy. I will try it to see if I can directly can member function of baseActionCounter. @songyuanyao, may I know how did you learn templates? I want to know enough to do these basic logical programming tasks. Material I find usually go into details of argument deductions which is just too complicated.

Comment: @bsobaid I learned templates from the book *C++ Templates: The Complete Guide*, you might want to check the [book list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/3309790). And cppreference.com is nice for learning too.